# How to convert a Git commit hash to a more readable and easy-to-memorize form?

Tags: git, hash, naming-conventions, git-commit

I put a git commit hash into each project build automatically, it looks like this:

```
0ba74ab23528b122923e83b5a7c6d2ce2e5a9313
```

It can hardly be easily read and remembered by a developer.

I have an option to use a short version of the commit hash that looks like this:

```
0ba74ab
```

Which looks better but there is still room to make it more readable and easy to memorize.

I think about generating a human-readable name for the hash which could be remembered and more or less stably mapped to a unique hash.

It could look like a string generated from a set of predefined strings with some suffix, like this:

```
drunk-coala-83
empty-pockets-95
```

Or just a synthetic vocable word like this:

```
jimakrow
```

As the project is not large and used only by me and a couple of my teammates, I can easily integrate it.

Is this technique used somewhere in projects? How can I tackle this problem so that to keep git workflow unaltered. Where should I start with this problem?

Comment: have you tried `git tag`?

Comment: you might want to check `git describe` with various options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [git tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) to name your commits.

Remember that you have to explicitly push the tags with `git push origin tag_name`, otherwise they just exist on your local.

Comment: Thanks! I have chosen https://github.com/dustinkirkland/golang-petname to generate nice unique names and put the script into a post-commit hook so that now they are put automatically and I got what I needed.